# My textFormField inserts new values at left, how to insert only at right

Tags: string, flutter, dart, textfield

I have a TextFormField which only accept numbers (4 at max). This value is the quantity of the item what the user wants, so, the first state is 0, and after user types the first value it updates, but I don't want to show the first zero (the initial state was 0, user typed 1, I want show only the number one and not the zero) so I added this code:

```dart
if (value.isNotEmpty && value != null && value[0] =="0") _controller.text = value.substring(1);
```

this is the TextField:

```dart
TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  // this is what i added
                  if (value.isNotEmpty && value != null && value[0] =="0") _controller.text = value.substring(1);

                  // some methods I take out cause is irrelevant
                  _setQuantity();
                  setState(() {
                    quantidade = int.tryParse(_controller.text);
                  });

                },
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(4),
                ],
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                ),
                cursorColor: AppColorSecondary,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: 
                  Colors.white,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

The Controller:

```
void _setQuantity() {
    Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: false).setQuantity(
        int.tryParse(_controller.text));
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = TextEditingController(text: getSize().toString());
    _controller.addListener(_setQuantity);
    quantity = widget.size.quantity;

    super.initState();
  }
```

So, after I added the line to hide the leading 0, the subsequent numbers typed are inserted in the right.For example:

```
// Initial state:
// 0
// Typed 3:
// 3
// Typed 2: (How is now)
// 23
// Typed 2: (HOW I WANT)
// 32
```

What can I do to reach my goal and insert the numbers at right without showing the leading zero (if there is another numbers after)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `initState`:

```
_controller = TextEditingController(text: getSize().toString() != '0' ? getSize().toString() : null);
```

in Widget:

```
if(_controller.text.isEmpty) _controller.text = '0';
```

Comment: i dont thing that it solve ltr textdirection issue?